# Codepipeline lambda action never complete

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

Well, my lambda function work's well according to the log's, but it never get completed in the codepipeline stage, I have already set permission to role for allow notificate pipeline ("codepipeline:PutJobSuccessResult",
        "codepipeline:PutJobFailureResult") and even set maximun time to 20sec but still not working (it actually ends at 800ms).

```
const axios = require('axios')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const url = 'www.exampleurl.com'

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  const codepipeline = new AWS.CodePipeline();

  const jobId = event["CodePipeline.job"].id;
  const stage = event["CodePipeline.job"].data.actionConfiguration.configuration.UserParameters; 

  const putJobSuccess = function(message) {
    var params = {
        jobId: jobId
    };

    codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {context.fail(err); }
        else     {context.succeed(message);}
    });
};

  const putJobFailure = function(message) {
    var params = {
        jobId: jobId,
        failureDetails: {
            message: JSON.stringify(message),
            type: 'JobFailed',
            externalExecutionId: context.invokeid
        }
    };
    codepipeline.putJobFailureResult(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        context.fail(message);      
    });
};

try {
    await axios.post(url, { content: stage})

    putJobSuccess('all fine')

} catch (e) {
    putJobFailure(e)
}
```

};

Answer (score 5):

## The root issue

Because nodeJS runs everything async by default, `codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult` is being run async. The issue seems to be that the Lambda function is finishing it's execution before `codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult` has a chance to complete.

## The solution

Run `codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult` synchronously so that it is forced to complete before the response is returned to Lambda for the lambdaHandler.

```
const putJobSuccess = function(id) {
    //await sleep(60);
    console.log("Telling Codepipeline test passed for job: " + id)
    var params = {
        jobId: id
    };
    return codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(params, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err)
        } else {
            console.log(data) 
        }

    }).promise()
};

exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {

    ...   
    await putJobSuccess( jobId )
    return response

};
```

Comment: Thank you!! Been debugging this for about 4 hours now and you helped me realise it was because the Lambda was exiting before sending the job success result. It's worth noting you can also achieve this by saying `await codepipeline.putJobSuccessResult(...).promise()`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see this issue, most of the time it is due to 'PutJobSuccessResult' never being invoked. The best way to check this is to go to CloudTrail > 'Event History' and look for 'Event name' = 'PutJobSuccessResult' during the time range you expect the Lambda function calling this API. Probably you will not find the 'PutJobSuccessResult', then please have a look at the code again and the Lambda execution logs in CloudWatch.